# How to use protobuf message as java class without a java outer class?

Tags: java, protobuf-java

I want to generate java class with My.proto:

```
package com.my.test;

option java_package = "com.my.test";

message MyError {
  optional string value = 11;
  optional string name = 12;
}

message MyRequest {
  optional string myid = 1;
  optional string yourid = 2;
}
```

After use `protoc --java_out=./ My.proto`, there will be: `com.my.test.My.java`

```
package com.my.test;

public class My {
  public static class MyError {}
  public static class MyRequest {}
}
```

How could I generate java class like:

```
package com.my.test;
public class MyError {}
```

and

```
package com.my.test;
public class MyRequest {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to generate classes without an outer class, you can import the inner classes:

```
import com.my.test.My.MyError;
import com.my.test.My.MyRequest;
```

Alternatively, if you are using proto3:

```
syntax = "proto3";
option java_multiple_files = true;
```

Comment: This is not the solution for the question.

Comment: @Debjit Adding `option java_multiple_files = true` seems to be. ‍♂️